# garbage data printed on accessing struct array

Tags: c++, malloc

I am trying to run the following code but it gives me garbage data on accessing the struct array values. Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Once I move the malloc part to the main function it seems to work. But I want to keep the malloc in a separate function.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
 *
 */
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
} CoordinateData;

void tester(CoordinateData* cd_data){
    cd_data = (CoordinateData*)malloc(5*sizeof(CoordinateData));
    CoordinateData data = {41.2525,74.0744};
    *cd_data = data;

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    CoordinateData* cd_data;
    tester(cd_data);
    std::cout << (*cd_data).x << "::" << (*cd_data).y << std::endl;
}
```

The output I get is 2.42126e-39::-1.51015e-05
The expected output is 41.2525::74.0744

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you allocating memory for 5 `CoordinateData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass cd_data by *address*, not value:

```
void tester(CoordinateData** cd_data)
{
    *cd_data = (CoordinateData*)malloc(5*sizeof(CoordinateData));
    CoordinateData data = {41.2525,74.0744};
    *(*cd_data) = data;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CoordinateData* cd_data = NULL;
    tester(&cd_data);
    std::cout << (*cd_data).x << "::" << (*cd_data).y << std::endl;
    free(cd_data);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS
}
```

Note also, the return value of `main()` which you were missing. Also. this question is tagged as both C and C++. If it is the latter, use `new` and `delete[]` instead of `malloc` and `free`

Answer (score 2):

Because the `malloc` assigns memory to a copy of the pointer you pass to your function.
The pointer you pass to the function never gets assigned with any memory or data.

You need to **Pass by reference**.

```
//Call function as
tester(&cd_data);

//Function Implementation
void tester(CoordinateData** cd_data)
{
    *cd_data = (CoordinateData*)malloc(5*sizeof(CoordinateData));
    CoordinateData data = {41.2525,74.0744};
    *(*cd_data) = data;
}
```

Comment: then how can i access it from main?

Comment: @user949110: same way as you did previously, You only need to pass the address of the pointer and not the pointer itself to the function.